# How to set DisplayMemberPath and SelectedValuePath for a binding from DataRow from System.Data?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How to set DisplayMemberPath and SelectedValuePath for a binding from DataRow from System.Data?

This is what I am doing, is it wrong?

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable("tb1");
dt.Columns.Add("ID");
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
ds.Tables.Add(dt);

DataRow dr1 = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
dr1["ID"] = 1;
dr1["Name"] = "Edwin";

DataRow dr2 = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
dr2["ID"] = 2;
dr2["Name"] = "John";

DataRow dr3 = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
dr3["ID"] = 3;
dr3["Name"] = "Dave";

ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr1);
ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr2);
ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr3);

comboBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
comboBox1.SelectedValuePath = "ID";

foreach (DataRow item in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: Instead of doing all that `magic strings` stuff with `System.Data`, why don't you create a Class to hold that information? with a `string Name {get;set;}` and an `int Id {get;set;}` property?

Comment: Are you missing DataBind() on the comboBox..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding `DataRow` objects to your `ComboBox`, and `DataRow` does not have properties titled `ID` and `Name` (well technically they do have a `Name` property, but it's not the one you're thinking of)

An easy way to remember is to use `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath`, you need to be able to access the property using the syntax of `DataItem.PropertyName`, so in your case it's trying to access `DataRow.ID` and `DataRow.Name`

For example, `DisplayMemberPath` is just a shortcut to a data template that looks like

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayMemberPathValue}" />
```

You'd be better off just adding something simple like a `KeyValuePair<int,string>` or a custom class, or even just a `ComboBoxItem`

```
comboBox1.SelectedValuePath = "Key";
comboBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";

foreach (DataRow item in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(
        new KeyValuePair<int,string>((int)item["ID"], row["Name"] as string));
}
```

Comment: thanks for your time answering the questions, but I'm intrigued how to wrap the datacolumn on the SelectedValuePath. It seems logical that it won't be simple "ID" but I maybe it is accessible though going in a lower level "row.column.ID", Do you know what I mean